# Find the number of even parity numbers between two integers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to find the number of even parity numbers between two integers. Here is what I've written so far:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define fastio                        \
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); \
    cin.tie(NULL)
#define ll long long int

bool findParity(ll x)
{
    ll y = x ^ (x >> 1);
    y = y ^ (y >> 2);
    y = y ^ (y >> 4);
    y = y ^ (y >> 8);
    y = y ^ (y >> 16);

    if (y & 1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void solve()
{
    ll a,b; cin >> a >> b;
    ll evenparity = 0;
    for(ll i = a; i <= b; ++i){
        if(findParity(i)==0) evenparity++;
    }
    cout << evenparity;
}

signed main()
{
    fastio;
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine. However, the difference between the two integers `a` and `b` can be as high as `10^11`, which means that an `O(n)` solution like this would not work. Is there a more efficient i.e `O(1)` solution to this problem?

Comment: Just a thought - this feels like it should be possible to be calculated, as the bit patterns are predictable. There might be the need to enumerate a few starting and ending cases.

Comment: Yeah, and the constraints wouldn't be so high if an `O(1)` approach isn't possible

Comment: Are a and b to be counted as well if they have even parity ?

Comment: `Yeah, and the constraints wouldn't be so high if an O(1) approach isn't possible` - false. `O(log(n))` would work just fine for the constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a function which calculates the even parity numbers from [0-x] interval, let's call it sumParity, then simply return sumParity(b)-sumParity(a-1).  (If I understood properly you are looking for the [a,b] closed interval.)

If start counting the parity from zero, and pair the numbers, (0-1), (2,3), (4,5) then each of these pairs has exactly 1 even and 1 odd parity. (These pairs only differ in the lowest bit).

So, if x is odd, then sumParity(x) = (x+1)/2, otherwise x/2 + parity(x).

(You already has the parity(x) function)

f(a,b) = sumParity(b)-sumParity(a-1)

It works only for positive integers, but you can easily extends the logic to negative numbers too.

Comment: Thanks for the crystal clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Every even/odd pair of integers contains exactly one even parity number.

So it suffices to check if a and b are even parity numbers and see if they contribute to their own even/odd pair, and count the intermediate pairs. This is O(1).